# In openJPA, does queryCache require a RemoteCommitProvider?

Tags: caching, persistence, openjpa

In openJPA 2.4, if I set :

`<property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="true"/>`

but DO NOT SET   `openjpa.RemoteCommitProvider`  property, I get the following error :

org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: You have attempted to use a RemoteCommitListener without also specifying a RemoteCommitProvider.  In order to use a remote commit listener, you must configure a remote commit provider to use through the openjpa.RemoteCommitProvider configuration property.

This configuration used to work in openJPA 1.X

Does anyone know if QueryCache absolutely requires a `openjpa.RemoteCommitProvider` or does this look like a bug in openJPA ?

The documentation mentions that `openjpa.RemoteCommitProvider`  is required for `openjpa.DataCache` but it doesn't mention that for `openjpa.QueryCache`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you've encountered is an oddity of a configuration problem. From what I can tell, you must have the QueryCache enabled, but not the DataCache.? If that is not true, please ignore the rest of my post.

From what I recall when you enable `openjpa.DataCache` the runtime automatically configures a RemoteCommitProvider for you. The RCP is required when using the DataCache/QueryCache. In your case if you only have the QueryCache enabled, the RCP doesn't get auto configured.

I'm still scratching my head why you are configuring the QueryCache without the DataCache? This is a very odd use case as with this setup it is very unlikely that you'll ever have a cache hit and you're paying the price of a cache that isn't helping you.

Comment: Correct, QueryCache but no DataCache.   I can't say for sure that his is supposed to be helpful in terms of caching, but what I can tell you is that this configuration works in JPA 1.X and fails in 2.4.X

The documentation is not very helpful in explaining these caches.....

Comment: Honestly I'm not certain what is really happening on 1.0.x? when you have this configuration. If you want, go ahead and open a JIRA with doc update to make things more clear?